# Android chromium: [FATAL:memory_linux.cc(36)] Out of memory

Tags: android, android-webview

I am working on tv app. i am using exoplayer2 lib for displaying videos and vast tag ads. after few hours video play i am getting below error. i don't know way i am getting this error because i am not using webview anywhere in my app and still i am getting this error.

if any knew about this error please let me know me.

Here is My Log file link
[Log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bqMlsrItOAsIRe9dcThNbGfyzRkE5M4x/view?usp=sharing)

Here is My Activity Code Link [BrightcovePlayerDemoExo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ViVIyrKjaw3_YKEPrMPZ0g8GZ1PxprSy/view?usp=sharing)